# Combined flair is still using old mSO icon instead of new mSE icon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, combined-flair

In the combined flair, the image used to represent Meta Stack Exchange is the old one used for Meta Stack Overflow. In the single flair, the new icon is used.

[image]

I assume this is not intentional. Can it be fixed, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The reason for this? Caching. Your flair is cached, and is only automatically updated every 24-48 hours. If you go to your network profile, and select *Sync with oldest profile*, it *should* update your flair with the new favicon.

Comment: Yep, mine has updated already.

Comment: Syncing the network profile with oldest profile did not update the flair. I am aware of caching, but thought it had been long enough. However, I will monitor it over the next few days.